# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) - trying to get an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

im trying to create a script that retrieves information from it, like article.php?id=1 returns a book and article.php?id=2 returns a computer. to accomplish this im trying to make an array with the table in it and i think my code is correct. i have my database "article" and the table "articles". and this is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// check connection

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['name'];
?>
```

Comment: try using blank i.e '' password

Comment: change `$password = "password";` to `$password = "";`

Comment: Also need to specify the `database` name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix `mysqli_*` API and `mysql_*` API. Use only `mysqli_*`

Comment: so no i just get no error but it doesnt print out the array that i attempted to make. any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Change your code with this:

```
<?php
$username="youruser";
$password="yourpassword";
$database="yourdbname";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database)
    or die( "Impossibile selezionare il database.");
?>
```

Comment: the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You shouldn't advice to use them, especially if the OP already uses the newer `mysqli_*`.

Comment: suppressing error messages is not going to help either.